# Transforming generating functions into algorithms that generate combinatorial objects

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms, generating-functions, trees

I've stumbled upon [this paper](http://algo.inria.fr/flajolet/Publications/DuFlLoSc04.pdf) where they write about random sampling of combinatorial objects. For sampling to be proper one has to know some core numbers (probabilities).

However, I'm not interested in sampling one object of some size out of a set of possible ones, I just want to enumerate (create) all of them.

For example, [this answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/368/counting-binary-trees) illustrates a nice construction of binary trees.

I've tried playing with trees and thought up of some nice constraints for which new generating functions could be discovered.

Let's say I want to generate all possible arithmetic expressions with $n$ values using a predefined set of operators.

$$((((((((x_1+x_2)+x_3)+x_4)+x_5)-x_6)+x_7)-x_8)\cdot x_9)$$

Above is one of the expressions I want to generate where $n=9$ and $\{+,-,\cdot\}$ the operator set. If I'm wondering how many of these are there, it's obviously (if I generate all possible operator trees) equal to Catalan(n) - multiplied by number of ways to color tree nodes with different operators (leaves of the tree are fixed values).

If I were to use only $+$ as an operator I'd have no need for brackets and the number of possible trees would be $1$ regardless of the chosen $n$.

Let's say I want to remove unnecessary brackets and count the trees with $n$ numbers and operator set $S = \{+,-,\cdot, /, \text{^}\}$ where commutativity, associativity and precedence applies.

I've managed to discover generating functions for all subsets of operator set $S$ (have no clue how to prove the thing but am confident they are correct).

For the given $S$ the generating function is

$$F(x)=1+xF(x)+4xF(x)^2+x^2{F(x)}^3\;.$$

Is there a way where I could, using this generating function, generate all of these constrained (no unnecessary brackets) trees without having to first generate all trees and then remove the unnecessary brackets?

Comment: Do you mean you want to count all distinct **numbers** this generates, or distinct **expressions** (in which case it would be better to use indeterminates $X_1, X_2, \ldots$ instead of $1, 2, \ldots$)?

Comment: Yeah, expressions, I'll edit it.

Comment: Are you including identities such as $(x\text{^} y)\text{^} z = x\text{^}(y \cdot z)$, which is true over the positive reals but not for complex numbers?

Comment: I am no expert on this but it would appear that Maple's **combstruct** package could be of use here.

Comment: @RobertIsrael I wasn't really thinking of numbers in particular, just on the simple properties of operators. http://lpaste.net/170857

So, nope, I wasn't really saying that (x/y)/z is equivalent to x/(y*z) or similar.

Comment: @MarkoRiedel I'm quite confident I could implement a part of the Duchon et al. paper (they describe how to inference generating function and other properties from the constrained combinatorial structure automatically) but I think that enumerating is far simpler than generating a random sample.

**combstruct** looks quite close to what I want, but it seems that I would have to define a specification, I guess if it's possible it could be derived from the given generating function.

Comment: The procedure is to build the specification first, then enumerate and compute generating functions, this is what **combstruct** does, amazing software BTW. Your example of enumerating syntax trees would appear to match what **combstruct** was invented for.

Comment: @MarkoRiedel yep, I've checked some references listed under the package and they seem to generate some complex structures, I'll see if there's any way to do this one. I think knowing if the brackets are redundant requires only the knowledge of parent operators and the current operator so it might be directly definable through a specification.